# Adh2 promoter in saccharomyces cerevisiae

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, gene-expression, synthetic-biology

I'm looking at expressing a protein in saccharomyces cerevisiae using the Adh2 promoter. My understanding is that the gene will be repressed by the presence of glucose, but when glucose runs out it should be activated. If my strain has deletions in ethanol biosynthesis, will Adh2 promoter still work?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? As long as you haven't deleted the transcription factor(s) that bind to the *Adh2* promoter, it should work just fine.

Comment: I'm coming across publications talking about ethanol encouraging dimerization of the transcription factor into it's active state, and I just wanted confirmation if ethanol is necessary.

Comment: Ah. In that case, feel free to ignore what I said and do more research. I don't know much about *Adh2* specifically (although I'm fairly well informed about transcription factors in general), so you'll have to see if the promoter is absolutely dependent on EtOH, or if that's just one way it's activated.